# AZCOPY_LOG_LOCATION - doesn't work in Powershell ISE?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azcopy

This is a really straight forward question, but does anyone know how to make the command AZCOPY_LOG_LOCATION actually work?

I'm doing:

```
Set AZCOPY_LOG_LOCATION=C:\backup\azcopylog\
```

and it doesn't get picked up. I've tried the below as well and nothing:

```
Set AZCOPY_LOG_LOCATION="C:\backup\azcopylog\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** in .ISE:

[image]

---

Original answer:

Please use `$env:AZCOPY_LOG_LOCATION="C:\backup\azcopylog"`.

I'm using the latest version of azcopy 10.3.4, and the log location is changed by using command above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that works within a PowerShell window, but not within a PowerShell file itself. Have you been able to make that work?

Comment: @Philip, you mean it does not work in powershell ISE?

Comment: @Philip, one more thing, you both set the log_location and then use azcopy to copy something in the ISE file?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Basically exactly the same as what you have within your screenshot.

Comment: @Philip, see the updated section in my answer, it's ok in ISE.